# Avoid Booking past dates with django

Tags: python, django

I have created an appointment booking system however i want to avoid any past dates being booked before it reaches create booking object which is then saved to the database.

Here is my views.py

class BookingView(View):

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, "availability.html")

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = AvailabilityForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        data = form. cleaned_data

    bookingList = Appointment.objects.filter(start__lt=data['end_time'], end__gt=data['start_time'])
    if not bookingList:
        booking = Appointment.objects.create(
            name=data["name"], 
            email=data["email"],
            start=data["start_time"],
            end=data["end_time"]
            )
        booking.save()
        return render(request, "success.html", {
            "booking":booking
        },)
    else:
        name = data["name"]
        return render(request, "booked.html",{
            "name":name, 
        },)
```

Comment: Pls, best ofuscate the sensible data in the code (email, zoom link...). Can you post the `AvailabilityForm` code?

Comment: Sure Thing. 
class AvailabilityForm(forms.Form):
name = forms.CharField(max_length=80, required=True)
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, required=True)
start_time = forms.DateTimeField(required=True, input_formats=["%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M", ])
end_time = forms.DateTimeField(required=True, input_formats=["%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M", ])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an extra validation to the date fields like this:

```py
from django.utils import timezone


class AvailabilityForm(forms.Form): 
    # ... the fields

    def clean_start_time(self)
        start = self.cleaned_data.get('start_time')
        if start < timezone.now():
            raise forms.ValidationError('the date must be after now.')
        return data
```

Can se more at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Next, you need little rewrite your view  and send the form to the template in order to display these errors, like explained in this docs:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/4.0/topics/forms/#the-view
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/4.0/topics/forms/#the-template